# Polars dataframe is keep on holding memory

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars, pyarrow

I am running my script in while True. In every hour it collect data from parquet and process it. It consumes around 50% of RAM, after completing the process I use del to delete the dataframe and do gc.collect() to collect any free memory but still not working. I am using lazy dataframe to collect data.

Here is my sample code

```
pa_dataset = pyarrow.dataset.dataset(source=dataset_path, format="parquet", partitioning="hive"
df1 = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(pa_dataset, allow_pyarrow_filter= True).filter((pl.col("timestamp") > start_date) & (pl.col("timestamp") < end_date))\
                                                                     .select('sourceIPAddress', 'destinationIPAddress', \
                                                                             'sourceTransportPort', \
                                                                             'destinationTransportPort', \
                                                                             'protocol', 'numPacketsCountIn', \
                                                                             'numPacketsCountOut')\
                                                                     .collect()
del df1
del pa_dataset
gc.collect()
```

My problem is it shloud release the acquired memory but it does not what should i do for that to happen.

Comment: Python doesn't release memory to the OS deterministically. https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/#:~:text=faster%20Python%20programs.-,Memory%20management,further%20use%20in%20the%20future.

Comment: You should take your script out of `while True` and have your OS launch it hourly with cron, windows scheduler, or whatever utility is relevant for your OS.